# Validate an input field for a date through Zend_Form with Zend_Validate_Date

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

```
    $this->addElement('text', 'projected-start', array(
        'required'   => false,
        'validators'  => array (
            array('date', false, array('MM/dd/yyyy'))
        ),
        'label'      => 'Projected Start:',
        'class'      => 'form-date'
    ));
```

I'm extending Zend_Form to create a new custom form. I tried to validate a date using the code above but it simply is not working and nothing is displaying when I enter an invalid input. Any help on this one?

EDIT:

```
class Application_Form_CreateProject extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    { ... }
}
```

Thats the start of extending the form.

```
$form = new Application_Form_CreateProject();
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
                                echo "true";
            }
        }
        $this->view->form = $form;
```

That's the controller

```
echo $this->form->setAction($this->url());
```

That's the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you get when you try this:

```
$f = new Zend_Form();
$f->addElement('text', 'projected-start', array(
    'required'   => false,
    'validators'  => array (
       array('date', false, array('MM/dd/yyyy'))
    ),
    'label'      => 'Projected Start:',
    'class'      => 'form-date'
));

$data = array(
    'projected-start' => '13/03/2011'
);
var_dump( $f->isValid( $data ) );
var_dump( $f->getErrors() );
die;
```

Comment: `bool(false)
array(1) {
  ["projected-start"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "dateFalseFormat"
  }
}
`

Comment: Well, then that works. So there must be something wrong with either the rest of your form, or with the `POST` data. Try `var_dump`ing your `POST` data and see if you get the expected result that should invalidate your form.

Comment: PS.: please expand your question with more code. Preferably code that shows how exactly you extend `Zend_Form` and build the elements. Also a minimal example of how you intitiate the form and how you pass in the data.

Comment: I put invalid input for the date but it says it passed validation. When I put valid inputs the same happens. Ok. Will do.

Comment: What is the *exact* date string you put in?

Comment: Hey, that's strange. With my example from above, it also passes. Then there must be something 'wrong' with the validator, or rather not behaving as expected.

Comment: BUGS BUGS BUGS BUGS BUGS BUGS

Comment: I think i'll just add another validation with regex to make sure its in the right format

Comment: Actually, 13/03/2011 comes out as valid

Comment: Be sure to read the docs also, if you haven't already. Might be some expected behaviour we are both not aware of.

Comment: I took a peek in `Zend_Validate_Date::isValid()`, it seems it uses `Zend_Date::isDate()` for validation when a format is given. And `Zend_Date` happily accepts just about all your inputs with your given format. So `Zend_Date` is behaving very unintuitive.

Comment: Ok, well I figured out one bug. Apparently you can't use dashes in the name of the input element. Now when you input 13/13/13 it says invalid. But, 123123 still returns valid. Thanks for the help, I'm going to regex for the rest of the loopholes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
$this->addElement('text', 'projected-start', array(
    'required'   => false,
    'validators'  => array (
        new Zend_Validate_Date(array('format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy'))
    ),
    'label'      => 'Projected Start:',
    'class'      => 'form-date'
));
```

Comment: Nope, I still get the same result.

Comment: And how do you check for valid?

Comment: `$form->isValid($request->getPost())`